# I am trying to install firebase via cocoapods but I get an error

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I have been trying to install Firebase using cocoapods on my project and I keep getting a weird error. I have spent the past few days trying to find a solution for this.

Pod File

```
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'LambdaTimeline' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for LambdaTimeline
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'FirebaseUI'
end
```

Error from terminal:

```
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.3)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit (5.15.1)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit (5.15.1)
Installing Firebase (6.19.0)

[!] Error installing Firebase
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git /var/folders/5c/rdypnj150p99zkp8cn55qty80000gn/T/d20200708-5128-bywz2w --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 6.19.0

Cloning into '/var/folders/5c/rdypnj150p99zkp8cn55qty80000gn/T/d20200708-5128-bywz2w'...
Note: switching to 'a43ca45c0dc9480fd16165eabc55e1cbaacc1b67'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

  git switch -c <new-branch-name>

Or undo this operation with:

  git switch -

Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

Updating files: 100% (3363/3363), done.
fatal: No url found for submodule path 'Firestore/Example/App/Testing' in .gitmodules
```

Comment: I did see something similar about creating a new user on the mac but I can't do this as it's a school computer. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please check your code and Remove first HEAD tag which is in your code. This HEAD tag created when you merge code from Your Source Control Repository.

Comment: Try `pod update`

Comment: I have tried pod update as well as reinstalling cocopods and still the same error occurs.